# node.js redis.get(key,callback) returns null randomly even after data and key both exist in redis db

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis, stackexchange.redis, node-redis

I am stuck in a very abnormal situation in node.js . I am using ioredis npm module to connect with redis database and saving keys in redis db 1.
In my application multiple api first get the data from a key and then get the data from another key which was returned from the first key.
In this case when 2 or more api hit comes on node instance. node js randomly gives null on the key even key exist in the redis database.
i have also tried to use an alternative to add settimeout to get key after sometime but still no success. Please check the code below

```
const userDataKey: any = await getUserDataFromRedis(`${UserConfig.USER_LOGIN_REDIS_PREFIX}${decodedData.id}_${decodedData.uuid}`)
            
const userData: any = await getUserDataFromRedis(`${userDataKey}`)


export const getUserDataFromRedis = async (key: string) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        redisConnection.select(UserConfig.REDIS_DB, (err) => {
            if (err) reject(err)
            console.log("this is the key : ", key);
            redisConnection.get(key, (error, data: any) => {
                if (err) reject(error)
                console.log("this is data : ", data);
                if (_.isNull(data)) {
                    console.log("NULL CONDITION MATCHED:",data);
                    setTimeout(() => {
                        redisConnection.get(key, (error, data: any) => {
                            if (err) reject(error)

                            console.log(`this is key and data if first time found NULL:${key},${data}`);

                            resolve(JSON.parse(data));
                        });
                    }, 1000);
                } else {
                    resolve(JSON.parse(data));
                }
            });
        })
    })
}
```

Can you please help me out what should be the reason, i get null sometimes even key exist in redis database.

```
this is data :  "rm_user_92"
this is data :  "rm_user_92"
this is data :  {"id":92,"name":"VinayRM1","email":"vinayrm20@yopmail.com","password":"$2b$10$0h5i.TiB6AENQF1c7XB1DOrBh/yNcKW9m3H.CM77wz.59IVfOjrEe","phone":"943434343434","is_active":"1","image":null,"user_type":2,"created_at":"2021-01-11T11:56:44.000Z","updated_at":"2021-01-11T06:26:44.046Z","added_by":1,"company":null,"country_code":91,"password_updated_at":"2021-01-29T19:14:01.000Z","device_token":"asdfdsafsadfasfsaf"}
Executing (default): Select U.*,A."id" as rm_id, A."name" as rm_name, A."email" as rm_email, A."phone" as rm_phone
                              FROM "user" U
                              LEFT JOIN "admin" A ON U."rm_id" = A."id" where U."id" = 172
Executing (default): SELECT * FROM "augment_view_analytics" WHERE import_date='2021-11-08' and user_id=172 and file_type=1;
Executing (default): SELECT * FROM "augment_view_analytics" where user_id = 172 and file_type=1 and import_date <= '2021-11-08' ORDER BY import_date DESC LIMIT 1;
this is data :  null
NULL CONDITION MATCHED: null
```

Comment: Not able to get any success till now to resolve this bug